# How to split string containing two dates in UTC format in json data

Tags: swift, date

In my app my `JSON` contains a string with two dates.

**My String**

```
"2017-07-22 00:00:00 SSS TO 2017-07-25 00:00:00 SSS"
```

I want the result in my tableView's `cellForRowAt` function:

- Expected Format:

  ```
  22 Jul - 25 Jul
  ```

my code that i have tried but the finaDate gives me nil. Where am i wrong, please correct me:

```
let dict1 = fiidiiOverviewArr[section].date

            let items = dict1?.components(separatedBy: " TO ")
            let date1 = items![0]
            let date2 = items![1]

            print(date1)
            print(date2)

            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM '-' dd MMM"
            let string = date1 + " - " + date2
            let finalDate = dateFormatter.date(from: string)
            print(finalDate)
            view.Header_date.text = "\(String(describing: finalDate))"
```

Comment: You can use the `.components(separatedBy: “ TO “)` to get both dates into an array. Then you would use a date formatter to put each one in the correct readable format (e.x. 22 July). Then you would concatenate both date strings with “ - “.

Comment: Can you give me an example sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Date` and `String` extension for this:

**DateExtension:**

```
extension Date {

    func dateToFormattedString() -> String {
        var formatter: DateFormatter?
        formatter = DateFormatter()
        /// "dd MMM" is your expected format, you can use whatever you want
        formatter?.dateFormat = "dd MMM"
        var returnValue: String?
        returnValue = formatter?.string(from: self)
        return "\(returnValue ?? "")"
    }
}
```

**StringExtension:**

```
extension String {
    func toDate() -> Date {
        var formatter: DateFormatter?
        formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter?.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter?.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        if let date: Date = formatter?.date(from: self) {
            return date
        } else {
            return Date()
        }
    }
}
```

And then you should create your trimming function:

```
func getTrimmedDates(with dates: String) -> [String]{
    return dates.replacingOccurrences(of: "SSS", with: "").components(separatedBy: "TO")
}
```

You should create formatter function:

```
func getFormattedDates(with dates: [String]) -> String {
    let joinedDates = dates.compactMap({ $0.toDate().dateToFormattedString() }).joined(separator: " - ")
    return joinedDates
}
```

**USAGE:**

```
let dates = "2017-07-22 00:00:00 SSS TO 2017-07-25 00:00:00 SSS"

let date = getTrimmedDates(with: dates)

let formattedDate = getFormattedDates(with: date)

print(formattedDate) /// You get "22 Jul - 25 Jul"
```

Comment: actually the json format is : "DATE": "2019-07-22 00:00:00.000 TO 2019-07-27 00:00:00.000" and i want 22 Jul - 27 Jul

Comment: you can modify this extensions but I will edit my answer for your benefit.

Comment: it is giving me 23 Jul - 23 Jul

Comment: the second date i am getting correct according to json data but the first date i am getting 23 jul in all dates

Comment: you should set `formatter?.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)` in `toDate()` function (String extension)

Comment: i have used the string extension as u have edit but the first date is coming wrong, in json data the first date is 22 jul, but i am getting 23 jul

Comment: and i have format like this 2017-07-22 00:00:00.000. what to change in above functions and extensions u gave?